# Implicit Function Theorem Question for $z$ defined implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

Suppose that $z$ is deﬁned implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$
by the equation

$$x^2 + y^z − z^3 = 0.$$

Calculate the partial derivatives $∂z/∂x$ and $∂z/∂y$ at $(x, y) = (1, 0)$.

This is what I have so far: I just want to know if I'm right.

$$∂z/dx = -Fx / Fz = -2x / (y - 3z^2) = 2 / (1 - 3z^2)$$

$$∂z/dy = -Fy / Fz = - z / (y - 3z^2) = - z / (1 - 3z^2)$$

Comment: To be clear, you want $y^z$, not $y^2$, right?

Comment: Your formula is correct. I assume that you can compute $F_x, F_y, F_z$ yourself and check that you've differentiated correctly.

Comment: According to his computation, he seems to mean $yz$, not $y^z$.